# Getting 405 error when trying to send email in form

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I'm trying to make myself a website, and found an awesome template online that could be used for free, but I can't get the email contact form to work. [Here](http://prntscr.com/gw5q13) is a link to the error, and [here](https://ahickman3.github.io) is a link to my website. I'm familiar enough with Web Dev that I can make basic websites with JS, but I've never used a php file. I've put my email in the php file, but past that, I don't really know how to go about this. [Here](https://codepen.io/fullmetal7777/pen/WZyYrp) I've provided the JS and php code relating to this question.

```
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/inc/sendEmail.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(msg) {`
```

(Just putting code here because it wont let me post a codepen link without posting code with it, which I don't quite understand). Also, a link to the github repository can be found [here](https://github.com/ahickman3/ahickman3.github.io). I've tried everything I can think of, but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub pages can only serve static content, and there is no way to run PHP on GitHub pages or upload things. That's why GitHub doesn't allow POST requests.

If you need server side scripting (E.g. PHP), you'll need to use a web host which offers these things.

Comment: Ah, I see. I tried doing it locally, which obviously didn't work. Then I used a chrome extension that created a web server, didn't work there either. That's a bummer. But otherwise, this would probably work right?

Comment: Yea.Need a web server to parse your php requests